# Apache is not starting after I deleted ssl certificate from certbot

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-18.04, lets-encrypt

Thanks you for taking the time out for helping. I am facing an issue with my apache server and the story goes like this:

I was running an ubuntu 18.04 server and my SSL(letsencrypt ssl obtained through certbot) got expired when I ran the command : `certbot renew` but it gave me errors relating to DNS. Then I thought it would be a good idea if I simply delete the existing certificate and install a new one so I googled how to delete a ssl certificate using certbot and got to know about `sudo certbot delete` but it didn't worked as expected and when I restarted the server apache didn't started and when I ran the command `apache2ctl configtest` it returned an error saying :

AH00526: Syntax error on line 20 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/tomebox.in/fullchain.pem' does not exist or is empty
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
Can anyone please help me understanding and resolving the issue and getting my website back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to edit the etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf file to change the file being referenced, as you have deleted that file. You can create a new certificate to reference using certbot instructions, or delete 000-default-le-ssl.conf altogether if you are no longer using SSL.

To edit the file, navigate to the directory in SSH using

```
cd etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

and then edit the file as root using

```
sudo nano 000-default-le-ssl.conf
```

ctrl+ x will exit and give option to save when done. You may want to restart apache2 after:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks Piers for the help.